# Cross region copy of Encrypted data in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms, amazon-rds

If I have to copy encrypted data in my RDS database from one region to another in AWS, what all options do I have based on the following design points:

1) My keys will be particular to a region in case I use services like CloudHSM or KMS

2) I do not want to have a Key management instance On Premise from where I can supply keys commonly to either regions

3) I am ok to encrypt the whole RDS or go for column based encryption